# which one has to consider for time complexity?

Tags: performance, time-complexity

nlog2n+3n^2+4n^3+n+10

from this polynomial what we supposed to consider either O(n^3) or O(logn) or any other..

from log2n we can have log2+logn right so it is logn .like wise

what we have to consider please tell me?

Answer (score 3):

In terms of time complexity, you always look for block which has highest impact on output.

```
nlog2n+3n^2+4n^3+n+10
```

In this, clearly n^3 is the block which has maximum impact of final output.
Big O always deals with upper bounds when value of n is high. for example, 
**n=1**

```
1log2(1) + 3(1*1) + 4(1*1*1) + 1 + 10
```

clearly all blocks will contribute to final value

**but if n=100**

```
1log2(100) + 3(100*100) + 4(100*100*100) + 100 + 10
```

In this, clearly n^3 will have maximum impact.impact of remaining is very minimal as compared to n^3.

Thus in your case n^3 should be considered as time complexity.

Comment: friendly advise, if you think answer was helpful then please upvote or accept :)

Comment: sorry i dont have sufficient points to up vote...that is the reason i could not make it...

Comment: For upvote and accepting answer of your own question you need atmost 1 reputation. Anyway its up to you :)

Comment: still it is showing same as u need 15 reputations minimum to upvote but idon't have...sry